# Looker - Remove default copy from schedule emails

Tags: looker

Can anyone advise on how to remove the default copy, "Results are attached" that resides in scheduled emails sent from Looker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to remove or customise the text within an email which Looker sends with an attachment. You can add your own comments to these emails using the settings in the schedule, but this will not replace the text you have indicated.